# Lotus Notes doesn't open from Dock

Tags: macos, lotus-notes, dock

Ever since installing Lotus Notes on my Mac I haven't been able to properly access it from the dock.

If the program is off then it will open up fine the first time but then clicking on the icon will not make Notes jump to the front of the screen.

It is only a minor thing but as it is the only program on my dock that I need to CMD-Tab to access it gets pretty annoying!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Notes version - 8.5.1
Mac OS X version - 10.6.2

Comment: Cheers for the edit Chealion.

Comment: Get a PC!! (Just Kidding, I'm on my iMac now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the latest OSX updates has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

DaveParillo's answer actually has nothing to do with the question. The IBM Lotus Notes/Domino 8.5 Forum thread linked to deals with the application not launching at all.

What Toby is saying is that Notes launches just fine, but after it has been hidden or pushed to the background by another application, clicking the dock icon doesn't bring Notes to the foreground.

That said, I had the exact same problem, and finally solved it. Previously, I had Notes installed in my personal *Applications* folder (i.e., */Users/blair/Applications*). When I upgraded to 8.5.1, Notes installed itself to the default location in the system *Applications* folder (i.e., */Applications*). Instead of putting the new version in my personal *Applications* folder and deleting the old version, I simply deleted the old version and left the new one right where it was. This, apparently, caused the problem. Today, I moved Notes into my personal *Applications* folder, and it works just fine.

In short, always keep Notes in the exact same location as it was when you launched it for the very first time, after the very first install.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a [known bug with a workaround](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/7756aedc25e6d81285256324005ac76c/66494d31e39c25f38525747b004ac850?OpenDocument) on the Notes 8 forum:

> We expect to have this fixed for GA. Notes uses a number of helper applications and there is a bug where the OS believes that one of these child processes is the real applications and launches it the next time you try to run Notes.
>
> For now, you can usually work around the problem by moving Notes out of the Applications folder temporarily and then move it back. This causes the Launch Services registry to get updated so it launches the correct process. Alternatively, you can run Notes from the command line using /Applications/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/maclauncher.

It seems like a fairly unsatisfactory workaround to me.